# Manually verifying signature in S/MIME mail with openssl

Tags: openssl, rsa, smime

I'm trying to manually verify the signature in an S/MIME signed email with openssl as part of a homework. While I have the mail and can extract the chain of certificates, I'm failing to extract the actual signature of the email and verify that it matches the mail content and senders certificate.

I have the public key of the signer (the last certificate) and I have the plaintext, which I got with

```
openssl smime -verify -in <mail> -noverify -out mail_body.txt
```

I also get the pk7 structure from the mail with

```
openssl smime pk7out -in <mail> -text -out certs.p7s
```

and dump the chain of certs

```
openssl pkcs7 -in certs.p7s -print_certs -text -out certs.pem
```

From this I get the certificate of the signer and his public key (Just copied the base64 begin/end certificate and

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -in signer.crt -out signer.key
```

If I understand correctly now I need the encrypted signed hash, decrypt it with the signer public key and check that with the hash of mail_body.txt but I can't find the signature in the mail.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand your problem. The signature of the message should be contained in the mail. It will be automatically  used - unless you explicitly give the `-noverify` option which you do for unknown reason.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm trying to verify it explicitly, getting the key, decrypting the signature and checking the hash, checking also the chain of certificates, etc. Of course If I use just run smime -verify I get that it is successful

Comment: So you are asking us to show where in your specific mail the signature is or do you ask us to point you to the standard where you can see how the signature can be stored in general? There can be two ways how the signature can be stored: detached and embedded. It is unclear what is the case with your specific message. See RFC 8551 for more details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I guess its embedded since its just one file, gonna read the RFC more thoroughly then..  I'll also edit my post because maybe its unclear what I'm doing.

Comment: @Aram: Every modern Email client can verify the signature and tell it if it is valid. Furthermore, Email Client will check also i the certificate itself is valid and if the whole certificate chain upstream is valid. Why are you doing this manually?

Comment: @mentallurg its homework >_<

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: actually `openssl smime -verify -noverify` only suppresses validation (aka verification) of the signer's cert against its chain and the truststore; it still verifies the signature in SignerInfo against the message, and only `-nosigs` suppresses the latter.

Comment: the option `smime pk7out` should actually read `smime -pk7out`. Maybe someone can correct the original question? I've tried but it somehow complains that my edit is less than 6 chars...